# How is the Gensim doesnt_match function working?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

Gensim implements a function called "doesnt_match" that return an outlier word from a list.

The function is called on a wordvector object.

model.wv.doesnt_match("breakfast cereal dinner lunch".split())
'cereal'

The documentation is not specifying how this function really work (what is the computation background)

Anyone knows ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can review the [`doesnt_match()` method's source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/1a73e4f110e0f199d39f9e051cbc081c4e2bab46/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py) – it's only 11 lines –
for the full details.

But the gist of it is...

- take the mean of all the word-vectors – a sort of 'center' for all candidates
- calculate the cosine-distance from that center to each word – this is the dot-product between unit-normalized versions of each relevant vector
- return the single word with the highest cosine-distance from that mean